# fnaddData Add JSON Object to a jQuery Datatable

Tags: c#, jquery, datatable

I just want to add this (Real JSON string example) :

```
[
    {
        "Name" : "Test",
        "EmpID" : "3232",
        "Station" : "123",
        "Action" : "123"
    }
]
```

to my jQuery datatable with `fnAddDate(jsonfile);`

But when I do it I get this :

[image: imageBug]

Which are the first 4 character of the JSON string..

Thanks for help!!!

Comment: try using parseJSON - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Comment: i got did and i got this error and an empty row :http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/17/bug5c.png/